# Define recursive function in pytorch

Tags: python, recursion, pytorch

Hi I need to define the following recursive function in pytorch which is updated at each new time step:

y_t+1(x) = y_t(x) ^ (1/(1+eta_t*lambda_t)) * exp (-eta_t * f_t(x)/(1+eta_t*lambda_t))

I wanted to know which is the most efficient way to define this function given that I will need to evaluate it many times.\

I thought about having some lists where I save the values eta_t, lambda_t, f_t(x) at each timestep t, but it seems time consuming given that I would need to iterate over the lists to obtain y_t+1(x).

Does anyone with more experience in pytorch know what is the best approach for this?

Right know given that the function is a probabilit function I am working in log probability and I have defined a class just for that function where I have defined the following function called at each timestep to update log_y:

def update(self, eta_t, lambda_t, f_t):
self.log_y = lambda x: 1/(1+eta_t*lambda_t)*(self.log_y(x)-eta_t*f_t(x))

But I get the following error once I call update and I try to evaluate log_y on a value of x:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

It seems that it is calling the update function recursively

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.